# Web Deploy from a new computer

Tags: azure, webdeploy, unauthorized

I got a new computer and I'm trying to publish my website through web deploy in Visual Studio from the new computer but it keeps saying failed due to unauthorized user. I'm using the same visual studio account, the same password. Everything else is identical to what it looks like in the old computer.

Is there something on the azure website that I need to update to allow a new computer to publish? Is the password different from the username/password I login to get into azure portal? There seem to be a lot more **** in my old computer's password input than what's required. I just assumed that it at some point did that for security purposes.

This is the error I get when going to Settings in the publishing window in Visual Studio and when I click Validate Connection:

> Connect to the remote computer ("website name" using the Web
>   Management Service, but could not authorize. Make sure that you are
>   using the correct user name and password, that the site you are
>   connecting to exists, and the credentials represent a user who has
>   permissions to access the site. Learn more at:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED.
>   The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

Comment: Open VS as Administrator and follow this "https://support.discountasp.net/kb/a1286/how-to-deploy-visual-studio-2013-web-application-project-to-discountasp_net-using-web-deploy-ftp.aspx"

Answer (score 0):

*Is there something on the azure website that I need to update to allow a new computer to publish?*

No.

*Is the password different from the username/password I login to get into azure portal?*

Its not different. Its the same.

I have noticed that sometimes, even with everything being correct from our side, VS web deploy to Azure simply may not work. It could a simple connection issue from VS to Azure, in terms of authentication and no fault of yours.

I don't know why VS is giving authentication error, but as an alternative, you could, deploy your site locally to a folder in Visual Studio. Then, deploy the site manually to your site via FTP.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-deploy

In the long run, you will come to trust FTP deploy than VS deploy which is simply too much of a hassle.